# Common property with all jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want create a property inside my object with all jQuery objects which it will use. I am a novice at JavaScript and that's why I want an advice. Can I do this in such a manner?

```
var myVar = {
    init: function() {
        //...
        this.obj = {
            id1: $('#id1'),
            id2: $('#id2'),
            id3: $('#id3')
        }
        this.method2();
    },
    method1: function() {
        alert(this.obj.id1.html()) // some work with id1
    },
    method2: function() {
        alert(this.obj.id1.html()) // some work with id1
    }
};
$(function() {
    myVar.init();
    myVar.method1();
});
```

Comment: do you mean that you have one function which many ids must use???

Comment: I have several functions which interact with common objects (ids)

Comment: What's the trouble? Your code does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/2HppG/

Comment: Yep, I am exploring more ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Only problem I could foresee with your code is that perhaps the DOM isn't ready when it is running:

```
var myVar = {
    init: function() {
        //...
        this.obj = {
            id1: $('#id1'),
            id2: $('#id2'),
            id3: $('#id3')
        }
    },
    method1: function() {
        alert(this.obj.id1.html()) // some work with id1
    },
    method2: function() {
        alert(this.obj.id1.html())
    }
};

  // run the init code (and any code that relies on init) after the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    myVar.init();
    myVar.method1();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/2HppG/1/

*(In the example, I removed the standard DOM Ready wrapping that jsFiddle provides by default.)*

Comment: @johnny: Yeah that can be confusing. It has tripped me a couple of times when testing code.

Comment: So exactly, I look into frame's code (jsFiddlefiddle.jshell.net/<guid>/show/)

Comment: @johnny: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can change your code placement using the menu on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You could try extending jQuery to use the methods directly on your elements.

```
$.fn.method1 = function () {
    alert(this.html());
    return this;
};

$("#id1").method1();
```

Ideally you would put these in your own namespace as to not pollute the jQuery namespace (to avoid conflicts etc.). You can read more about some of the best practices when extending jQuery [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: Yes, I understood that I should follow this way with my future script :)